Esp32 execute AT command from User-defined AT Command
How can I execute other AT command from User-defined AT Command?
For example
at_custom_cmd.c:
static uint8_t at_test_cmd_test(uint8_t *cmd_name)
{
    uint8_t buffer[64] = {0};
    snprintf((char *)buffer, 64, "test command: <AT%s=?> is executed\r\n", cmd_name);
    esp_at_port_write_data(buffer, strlen((char *)buffer));

    EXEC("AT+HTTPCGET="http://www.my.com");  // <-- How can I do it?

    return ESP_AT_RESULT_CODE_OK;
}


I tried to search exec command in offical site, but didn't find.

It's quite hard to understand what you're trying to do. If you want to send AT commands to a modem, then you open its serial port and write the command there; or use a pre-existing library like esp_modem to do it for you.

I developed user-defined command (see https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-at/en/latest/esp32/Compile_and_Develop/How_to_add_user-defined_AT_commands.html) . In this command I want to execute other AT command from Basic Set.

You need to register your AT command as per the documentation you provided. Have you done that? Why do you need custom AT command to run other AT commands while you could simply execute the original AT command directly?

Yes I done it. It's work fine.  Custom at command will be a wrapper for calling GET request. It will contain url login, password and additional information. This will simplify the exchange with the controller.

So what is your question? What is the meaning of "work fine" if you don't know how to execute the command?

Did you look at the code example at the beginning of the post? There I showed which place is causing me difficulties.

@hcheung "work fine" obviously means that without the EXEC line he is able to run "AT+TEST" and get an "OK" response, so the command is properly registered.

This question is not unclear and should absolutely not be closed as "Needs details or clarity".

Looking in the https://github.com/espressif/esp-at/ repository there is an at_exe_cmd function in components/at/src/at_self_cmd.c however do not use it as is, its signature and code prevents handling errors. Instead use it as a template to writing your own exec function.
The fundamentally flawed property is the const char *expected_response argument. You absolutely cannot just wait for an "OK" response, you must be able to accept all possible final result codes. So using strstr is wrong, and the response lines needs to be properly parsed. I have covered this aspect in this answer for a similar scenario.
Also using a global variable like at_self_cmd_t *s_self_cmd is too spaghetti, you can do better than that.

The current version does not allow implementing the example. I am providing the answer from the official forum.

Sorry that it’s an unsupported usage. because both at_test_cmd_test() and AT+HTTPCGET=params are executed in at_process_task(), however, in the current design, command processing is linear, and you cannot execute another command before one command is completed.
in you case, you can create another task, and in your task, to execute some command like AT+HTTPCGET=. and at_test_cmd_test() to get the status of your task.

